# Looping Different Data Sets and Predicting with LSTM

Tags: python, keras, jupyter-notebook, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

I've been working on keras, LSTM for a while now but still fairly new.

I am facing an issue where I would need to restart Jupyter Notebook every time I train and predict with keras LSTM.

This would post a problem when I need to loop multiple predictions with different data sets, using the same LSTM model setup.

An alternative is to train and predict data set by data set, restarting and running all after every prediction is completed, which would be a very tedious process.

for example:

```
for i in ...: # Loop for different data set

    ...

    # Create LSTM Model
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(LSTM(units=32,
                   activation='relu',
                   batch_input_shape=(1, timestep_n, feature_n),
                   return_sequences=True))
    model.add(Dense(units=1, 
                    activation='relu'))
    model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer=adam, metrics=['accuracy'])
    ...

    # Train Model
    model.fit(x, y, epochs=100)

    ...

    # Predict
    result = model.predict(x_p)

    # End Loop for next data set
```

I have tried clearing the session before I create every model for training but the values predicted are different from when I was running a single training and prediction.

```
    session = tf.get_default_session()
    if session is not None:
        session.close()
    K.clear_session()
    gc.collect()
```

I have also used random seed in hopes of getting the same value every run. For consistency.

```
    SEED = 1
    np.random.seed(SEED)
    tf.set_random_seed(SEED)
    random.seed(SEED)
```

I am thinking of declaring/creating a "NEW" LSTM model in every loop to predict values of different data sets, without having to manually restarting the notebook and running for every data set.

Even if I perform `del model` at the end of the loop, somehow the memory is not properly cleared.

Could someone help with this?

Comment: why are iterating through the LSTM model?

Comment: Essentially to decrease manual effort to load different data set in different runs of the codes. I was hoping for, in the loop, I could restart a LSTM model to train and predict the values for different data set, starting a "Clean state" or "New" LSTM model in every loop, so that the subsequent data set will not be training on top of the previous model in the loop.

Comment: try building a model function and then call the function at each loop  `model=MyModel()`, and then your  all `model.compile`,`model.fit` and `model.predict`, and then store the results

Comment: Hmm... I've tried it but the results of the prediction is still the same. Might be something to do with the LSTM state not being reset after every loop or something is holding the memory. It does not make sense as to why the memory of the old model is affecting the new model.
Setting LSTM stateful = True, doesn't solve this, as i am also using return_sequence = True.

Answer (score 0):

What are you getting for this:

```
for i in ...: # Loop for different data set

...

model = None
# Create LSTM Model
model = Sequential()
...
```

Comment: For example of a single data set (ID: 25) (Not the actual data set numbers), I have 11 numbers for Input Sequence [35, 37, 42, 36, 36... 24] and the expected output is 26

Just by running one LSTM model alone for this single data set, it will predict the output 29 (without clearing Keras Session).

But once I've placed it in a loop, with other IDs running before ID:25, the output predicts 33. And with clearing of Keras session, output 31.

Comment: But if i'm running ID:25 first in the loop, it will predict output 29 (without clearing Keras Session), But subsequent IDs will be different.

I do understand that the numbers a a little random in terms of the sequence hence the accuracy.

But i noticed that clearing of Keras session will give me output 31 regardless of loop or not.

Apologies my phrasing of words.

Comment: I might not understand you or the API, but in each iteration you are adding to LSTM model (model.add), so how could it be the same?

Comment: model.summary() gives me the same number of layers in every loop.
results are the same even though I used del model at the end of the loop.
I believed that model = Sequential() should start a new model?
If so how do i create a new model?

Comment: What happens if you do as suggested in the answer place: model = None before defining the model in each iteration?

Comment: Doesn't work. I am beginning to suspect it might be just Keras LSTM model.