# Trying to implement Random Search for a LSTM model

Tags: python, keras, lstm

I am implementing a random search for the LSTM architecure for forecasting problem. So, for example, if I train the model only once, it gives me a mean absolute error of 0.023, then in the same script I train a new model again but with the same parameters the result is different, I have a mean absolute error greater than 0.024 and if I do more training the mean absolute error increases. After each training I use keras.backend.clear_session() and try to save each model in a new variable despite having the same parameters, also try: initial_epoch=0. And it is not only when the same model is trained, for example if I train a different model(parameters like units or layers) I get a mean absolute error of 0.025, and if I want to train the model of the previous example the mean absolute error is another value different and greatter from the expected one if only to that I see a similar post with no response: [Looping Different Data Sets and Predicting with LSTM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60037006/looping-different-data-sets-and-predicting-with-lstm) and this [Iterating through different data sets with LSTM without retaining memories of previous training](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67774590/iterating-through-different-data-sets-with-lstm-without-retaining-memories-of-pr/71128478#71128478)
Does anyone know how to solve this problem or a way to implement GridSearch for an LSTM model?

Comment: Hi and welcome to StackOverflow. It will help you get answers if you can post some of the code that you have tried.